# How to model optional product delivery companies

Tags: mysql, database-design

I would like to model the following in my database. I have several ways to deliver a *product*. Each *product* can be sent by only some, or by every *method of delivery*.

In my current design every *product* has a table where I type available  *methods of delivery*, for example: `ups;dhl;fedex`.

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: I re-worded the question. I hope I got it right; apologies if I have not. You can edit the question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
( PRODUCT_ID ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE DELIVERY_COMPANIES
( COMPANY_ID ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
, 
);
```

I assume what you mean by `ups;dhl;fedex` is a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_DELIVERY_COMPANIES
( PRODUCT_ID ... NOT NULL
, COMPANY_ID ... NOT NULL
, ...
,    CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) 
     REFERENCES PRODUCTS (PRODUCT_ID)
,    CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY_ID) 
     REFERENCES DELIVERY_COMPANIES (COMPANY_ID)
,    CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID, COMPANY_ID) 
);
```

and that seems about right.